# Section and sub-section command or referencing doesn't work in overleaf document

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, overleaf, templates, subsection

I cannot refer to a section or subsection in the main text of my overleaf document using this command:

Section~\label{sec:X}

I am sharing the code of the document below and it gives the following result:

I want to place the reference here, Section.

```
\documentclass[12pt,aps,prl,letterpaper,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}
\begin{document}

\section{S2. How to make a section}
\label{sec:buildsection}

I want to place the reference here, Section~\ref{sec:buildsection}


\end{document}
```

Comment: your posted code is not an example of the problem you are asking about. Show an example with a section reference that does not work, then we can debug it

Comment: Please have a look at the code now, after \begin{document}

Comment: \section{S2. How to make a section}
\label{sec:buildsection}

I want to place the reference here, Section~\label{sec:buildsection}

Comment: No please fix your question remove any packages not needed to show the problem and add an example of the problem,  `Section~\ref{sec:buildsection}` should work on the second run of latex.

Comment: You get `LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.`

Comment: `Section~\label{sec:buildsection}` should be `Section~\ref{sec:buildsection}`

Comment: It still doesn't work using Section~\ref{sec:buildsection}

Comment: @daleif it was revtex until the last edit (and I can reproduce now)

Comment: I am using \documentclass[12pt,aps,prl,letterpaper,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}

I have edit the question and added it there also.

Comment: @AliBabar thanks for the edits, I can confirm it doesn't work, looking...

Comment: Ok, that was new, not even a warning

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not compatible with recent `hyperref` judging from the contents on the `\newlabel` line in the aux. That looks very odd, it is returning the empty string.

Comment: @daleif yes (see chat)

Answer (score 5):

With the options you used the class uses unnumbered sectioning commands. You can't reference them automatically, but have to do it manually as you did it in the title text:

```
\documentclass[12pt,aps,prl,letterpaper,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document}
\section{S2. How to make a section}\label{sec:buildsection}


I want to place the reference here, Section~S2

\end{document}
```

You could change the `secnumdepth` counter to get numbered sections and then references would work. But normally it is not a good idea to change the layout of a journal class, they want it as it is.

```
\documentclass[12pt,aps,prl,letterpaper,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\section{S2. How to make a section}\label{sec:buildsection}


I want to place the reference here, Section~\ref{sec:buildsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]